# Isolate a specific node and ancestors

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have an XML like:

```
<menu>
    <node id="home" url="url1.php">
          <label>Homepage</label>
          <node id="user" url="url2.php"><label>User profile</label></node>
          <node id="help" url="url3.php"><label>Help page</label></node>
     ...
    </node>
</menu>
```

Its used to generate a menu, the XML has `node` tags nested at any level under the first "home" `node`.
I pass a parameter called `$id` with PHP which gives the current active menu item.

(The `<label>` is in a separate tag and not as attribute because I've many labels for localization, actual xml is like `<label lang='en'>...</label><label lang='it'>...</label>`)

The idea is to use various XSLs to generate main menu, breadcrumbs, section titles (top menu).
For the main menu I've managed to do this:

```
<xsl:template match="menu">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//node">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>
               <xsl:if test="@id=$id">
                  <xsl:attribute name='class'>active</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:if>
               <xsl:attribute name='href'>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
               </xsl:attribute>
               <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
            </a>
            <xsl:if test="count(child::*)>0">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node" />
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And it works. But I'm stuck with the breadcrumbs.
How can I isolate only a specific node with `@id=$id` and his ancestors, to build breadcrumbs up to current page from home?

Resulting html should be, for a node ad the third nested level:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="url1.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="urla.php">Some child of home</a></li>
    <li><a href="urlb.php">Some grandchild of home</a></li>
    <li><a class='active' href="urlc.php">Current page which is child of the above</a></li>
</url>
```

Comment: Hello! Both questions should be straight-forward, but you might want to show your expected output in either case, just to be sure. Actually, you might want to consider asking question 2 as a separate question, to avoid the question and answers being too large. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC Thanks, I was already thinking of moving the other question apart... I'll edit my question :)

Comment: I think also X-Path will work for do this? See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_xpath.asp

Comment: @FIG-GHD742: please do not refer to w3schools; please see http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @FIG-GHD742: My question is clearly XSL-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breadcrumb you can do like this, by selecting the active node and then walking the ancestors, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--Obviously set your PHP variable here-->
        <xsl:variable name="id">bananas</xsl:variable>
        <!--Find this node somewhere in the tree-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//node[@id=$id]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <!--Walk the ancestors-->
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::node">
        <!--Snappy path separator here-->
            <xsl:text> --> </xsl:text>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="label/text()"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample Menu Xml:

```
<menu>
    <node id="home" url="url1.php">
          <label>Homepage</label>
          <node id="user" url="url2.php"><label>User profile</label></node>
          <node id="help" url="url3.php"><label>Help page</label></node>
    </node>
    <node id="products" url="urlN1.php">
        <label>Products</label>
        <node id="food" url="urlN2.php">
            <label>Food</label>
            <node id="fruit" url="urlN3.php">
                <label>Fruit</label>
                <node id="bananas" url="urlN4.php">
                    <label>Bananas</label>
                </node>
            </node>
            <node id="clothes" url="urlN3.php">
                <label>Clothes</label>
                <node id="shirts" url="urlN4.php">
                    <label>Shirts</label>
                </node>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</menu>
```

**Edit** Update - You've updated the Q to display the breadcrumb as a list - here's an updated template just in case :)

```
<xsl:template match="node">
    <ul>
        <!--Walk the ancestors-->
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::node">
            <li>
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="label/text()"/>
                </a>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: With some adaptation, works like a charm. Thank you so much... My main problem is understanding how to handle templates, the rest (for-each loop) is pretty strainghtforward, I just couldn't put it to use...